# Adb push contacts to Phone imports default to SIM. How to change the behavior to adb push to Phone Account?

Tags: android, adb, contacts, android-contacts, import-contacts

Whenever I try to import contacts using adb with a command like :

`adb shell am start -t text/vcard -d file:///sdcard/Folder1/vcard.vcf -a android.intent.action.VIEW com.android.contacts`

The contacts are pushed to SIM.

Traversing to this screen : " Contacts App -> Settings -> Account ". I see "SIM" as an account. I have to manually add another account for "Phone". Thereafter the adb push work as expected and imports contacts to Phone.

How do we achieve this using adb commands, without manual intervention ?

Answer (score 0):

This setting is internal to the `Contacts` app so you can't control it via ADB or any API.

You can potentially create a little app that takes a vcard file from the sdcard and saves the contacts on it to the Phone, but I don't think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Can you suggest a piece of code which can be used to select "Phone" as the target to save contacts ?

Comment: i don't think you can do that, but you can save it to the phone *yourself*, communication directly with the ContactsContract APIs and using the local Phone account as your RawContact's location